# Log of install.packages()

Tags: r

Does R by default store a log of the installation messages anywhere? If not, is there a way to have it log them on a file?

Sometimes I let R install various pacakges automatically, e.g.

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies=c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```

which can take hours and the installation log does not fit on the scroll buffer, so I can't see how the installation proceeded. It would be great if I can have R save this log somewhere (in addition to showing it on the terminal)

Comment: Is the output of `capture.output(install.packages("caret"))` sufficient? Or do you also require all the details regarding the mirror and download size?

Comment: @sebastian-c. I didn't know of `capture.output` Does that save (or redirect?) the output to a text file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need to know how the installation went (warnings and errors), the following may be sufficient for your needs:

```
sink("sink.txt")
install.packages("caret", dependencies=c("Depends", "Suggests"))
sink()
```

Comment: Thanks @sebastian-c, but I think this would not let me see the output on the terminal, which I would like, is that correct?

Comment: @user815423426 Possibly `sink("sink.txt",split=TRUE)` as detailed in `help(sink)`.

Comment: Why the `unlink` at the end?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg My own sloppy reading of the documentation. I've removed it.

Comment: Currently, it does not work, at least to me on Debian 9 with R 3.6.3. I get the sink.txt file empty

Comment: This doesn't store the output of any compilation steps e.g. a traceback if something fails. Neither does `split=TRUE`. It just outputs up to "building..."